# android media player on prepared listener on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

i am making a phone dialer app that play the sound when you press on button the app is working great but after a while i get a random crash because on prepared  listener i do not know what is happening and this is the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer$OnPreparedListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.alper.pola.andoid.phonedailer.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:258)
```

and this is how i cast the media player

```
if (mLastButton == one) {
                               MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;
                                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.one);
                                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                        mp1.start();
                                    }
                                });
                                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                        mp1.release();
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                            if (mLastButton == two) {
                                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;
                                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.two);
                                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                       mp2.start();
                                    }
                                });
                                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                        mp2.release();
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                            if (mLastButton == three) {
                                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;

                                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.three);
                                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                        mp3.start();
                                    }
                                });
                                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                        mp3.release();
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                            if (mLastButton == four) {
                                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;
                                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.four);
                                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                        mp4.start();
                                    }
                                });
                                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                        mp4.release();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
```

the app is working fine and the same button when i click on it is working but after while the button stop working and i get this crash with every button it start with working fine but after i type a few numbers the app crash

Comment: Please post the entire code of your Activity. It'll help to fix the issue more easily.

Comment: you are not making use of the "mediaPlayer" parameter being passed into the onPrepared method, instead of calling mp3 directly configure data source to mediaPlayer instance and pass that in

Comment: What do you mean by "type a few numbers"? Where? Is it always the same amount of numbers?

Comment: its always random amount of numbers all numbers are working okay but this happen randomly but it happen every time i use the app but in different ways

Comment: What is mp3 here in the code? Shouldn't you be using mediaPlayer object instead?

Comment: mp3 in audio for number 3

Comment: mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.three);

Comment: Include you activity code here. The snippet provided is not enough to answer your question.

Comment: prince bansal done

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very inefficient way while dealing with `MediaPlayer`. Still I'll help you a workaround with this code. Use `mediaPlayer.prepare()` to initiate the call. Checkout this code:

```
if (mLastButton == one) {

     mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.one);
     mp1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
             mp1.start();
     });
     mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
             mp1.release();
           }
     });
     mp1.prepare();

}
```

Do similarly for others. There are much better way to do this but as with your code, this is shortest.